# how to use responseToSelector in swift?

Tags: swift, delegates

In my swift project, I have my custom delegate class. Like in objective-c, I can use my delegate

> [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:)]

But I cannot use it in swift.

here is my code

```
import UIKit

protocol Popup1ViewcontrollerDelegate {
func cancelButtonClicked(sender:Popup1ViewController)
}

class Popup1ViewController: WCViewController {

var delegate : Popup1ViewcontrollerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.delegate && self.delegaterespondsToSelector("cancelActionClicked:")) {
        self.delegate?.cancelButtonClicked(self)
    }
}
}
```

and error image
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: @KittMedia yes. Please help me.

Comment: Go back to the WWDC videos, and look at the very, very, _very_ first video which answers exactly that question and points out how much better Swift is for not needing respondsToSelector.